# Can still see CONSTRAINTs after running ALTER TABLE [mysch].[mytablename] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL but why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, constraint

I am looking at a piece of code in a proc that seems to disable but never reenable constraints, namely

```
ALTER TABLE [mysch].[mytablename] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

but after the actions are taken in the code below, there is nothing to reenable them.

I even tried just running that 'NOCHECK' statement as a single line to see what happens i.e. ignoring the rest of the code in the proc.

I am assuming they are still enabled because if I go to Object Explorer, Tables (plus a right click 'refresh') then script the table out, I can see dozens of lines like

```
ALTER TABLE [mysch].[mytablename]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_mytable_othertable] FOREIGN KEY([othertable_ID])
REFERENCES [mysch].[othertable] ([othertable_ID])
GO
```

What is going on here?
I have trawled other objects using Red Gate's SQL Search to look for ALTER TABLE..CHECK statements to no avail.

Is object explorer incorrectly displaying the constraints or is something else at work here?

Answer (score 3):

### What is going on here?

Someone "disabled" all the constraints on a table, which is somewhat common before large data modifications when the process of checking the constraints slows the process down more than re-enabling them later.

Just because constraints are not checked doesn't mean they're dropped. You can see the `NOCHECK` syntax in the constraint syntax that you copied in.

You can see which constraints might be disabled, or not trusted, by querying views describing them:

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    c.is_not_trusted,
    c.is_disabled
FROM sys.check_constraints AS c
WHERE c.is_not_trusted = 1 
OR    c.is_disabled = 1;

SELECT
    f.name,
    f.is_not_trusted,
    f.is_disabled
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
WHERE f.is_not_trusted = 1 
OR    f.is_disabled = 1;
```

For more details, see my posts:

- [Data Loading and Referential Integrity](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/data-loading-and-referential-integrity/)
- [Untrusted Foreign Keys Still Check New Data](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/untrusted-foreign-keys-still-check-new-data/)

Scripts to re-enable/trust constraints (reproduced from the first link):

```
SELECT N'ALTER TABLE ' 
       + QUOTENAME(s.name) 
       + N'.' 
       + QUOTENAME(o.name) 
       + N' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT '
       + QUOTENAME(f.name) AS utrusted_fk
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON f.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE f.is_not_trusted = 1;

SELECT N'ALTER TABLE ' 
       + QUOTENAME(s.name) 
       + N'.' 
       + QUOTENAME(o.name) 
       + N' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT '
       + QUOTENAME(c.name) AS utrusted_ck
FROM sys.check_constraints AS c
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON c.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE c.is_not_trusted = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL is very confusing in its syntax. You have two aspects of a constraint:

1. Is it enabled or disabled?
2. If there a potential for having "invalid" data in the table?

For point 2 above, there are two scenarios

1. You added the constraint without checking existing data
2. You disable the constraint and then when you re-enabled it, you didn't check existing data.

The syntax is confusing because it uses the words CHECK for both the concept of "check existing data" and "enable or disable the constraint". This lead to commands such as below. There are no typos in below code!

```
--Enable constraint without checking existing data
ALTER TABLE t WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT t_ch

--Enable constraint AND check existing data
ALTER TABLE t WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT t_ch
```

There is, as Erik show us, meta-data with which you can check this.

1. The is_not_trusted column tell us whether you added or enabled the constraint without checking existing data (WITH CHECK or WITH NOCHECK)
2. The is_disabled tell us if the constraint is enabled or disabled (CHECK or NOCHECK)

I wished that ANSI would have chosen the words DISABLE and ENABLE to disable and enable a constraint, that would make the commands much easier to understand...

Examples with comments:

```
USE tempdb
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t
GO

CREATE TABLE t(c1 int)
GO

--Add the constraint without checking existing data
ALTER TABLE t WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT t_ch CHECK(c1 > 10)
GO

--Constraint is enabled, below fails
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1)
GO

--Disable constraint
ALTER TABLE t NOCHECK CONSTRAINT t_ch
GO

--Constraint is NOT enabled, below executes successfully
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1)
GO

--Enable constraint without checking existing data
ALTER TABLE t WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT t_ch
GO

--Constraint is enabled, below fails
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1)
GO

--Disable constraint
ALTER TABLE t NOCHECK CONSTRAINT t_ch
GO

--Enable constraint AND check existing data, command fails because of invalid data in table
ALTER TABLE t WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT t_ch
GO

--Check of data in a table violates a constraint (not ANSI SQL, obviouly)
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS(t_ch)
```